# Show / Hide Button in Sencha Touch 2.3.1 losing reference

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

So I have a problem in my sencha touch app. I have a container defined:

```
{
            xtype: 'container',
            text: 'SOMETHING',
            height: '15%',
            width: '15%',
            itemId: 'optionsMenu',
            hidden: true,
            style: 'background:red',
},
```

And I have a listener defined in Listeners:

```
{
            fn: 'onOptionsButtonTap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#optionsButton'
}
```

and finally my onOptionsButtonTap() method:

```
onOptionsButtonTap: function() {
    var optionsPanel = this.down('#optionsMenu');
    console.log(optionsPanel.isHidden());
    if(optionsPanel.isHidden()) {
        optionsPanel.showBy(this.down('#optionsButton'));
        //optionsPanel.addAfterListener('tap', this.onOptionsButtonTap);
    }
    else
        optionsPanel.hide();
},
```

What i want to do is when I tap the button, the container will appear by the button. But when I am tapping the button next time, I am getting a TypeError, saying that optionsPanel does not have a method isHidden(). What is causing this? I tried using panel as well (hence the variable name) but that is giving the same error.

Comment: I don't have time to test it but if I had to guess `showBy` is turning the menu into a ***floating*** component and possibly removing it from the optionsPanel (so `down` can longer find it).  If that is the case then you will either have to keep a permanent reference somewhere outside the function or find it out-with the container altogether using `Ext.ComponentQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a name of the container.

```
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                text: 'SOMETHING',
                name: 'option_menu',
                height: '15%',
                width: '15%',
                hidden: true,
                style: 'background:red'
            }
```

In your controller just create a reference of this `optionMenu: 'container[name="option_menu"]` option_menu and on `tap` event of button call this function from the controller.

```
onOptionsButtonTap: function(button) {
        var me = this, optionsPanel = me.getOptionMenu();
        console.log(optionsPanel.isHidden());
        if(optionsPanel.isHidden()) {
            optionsPanel.showBy(button);
        }
        else{
            optionsPanel.hide();
        }
    }
```